# Eclipse remote system explorer and sudo

Tags: eclipse

I use Eclipse RSE to access files on a web server. To establish a sftp connection with Eclipse RSE I use my HippieBandJam user-ID. To edit files I need root access which I only can gain with the sudo command. In Eclipse RSE I have tried to start a new ssh terminal, use sudo su and then refreshed the sftp tree but this does not seem to work. Does anyone have any idea how to "upgrade" the sftp connection so I can edit the files?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same thing.  I notice in programs like winscp, you're able to set specifics regarding the sftp subsystem: ie: sudo su -c /usr/lib/sftp-server.  I haven't been able to find an option like this in remote systems explorer .....

Comment: I still have not found a solution to this. The way I do it now is that I, in Eclipse, open the file that I want to edit, copy the content and save it to a local copy, make the changes, upload it to my home directory where I have write access. Then I just use the terminal with sudo to overwrite the old file with the one in my home directory. It's not a fun way to do it but it works when I dont have to update a lot of files.

Comment: I'm with you on the pain aspect.  Maybe someone else has a better integration?  I've gotten this to work with winscp, but I would prefer to stay in my development environment ......

Comment: all the answers are fail :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want something really exotic, you could:

1. Compile a tiny program in C that does the only thing: execs the shell
2. Set a suid bit for the executable
3. Create a new user and set our freshly compiled binary as this user's login shell
4. Set up proper permissions for the binary, allowing only the new user to execute this file
5. Use new user's credentials to log onto the server

He-he :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea:

create a mount point in your local system in /media/

use sshfs cmd to mount the remote server file system directory to .

In eclipse use the project, use add  directory to your project
Steps: right click on your project -> New -> Folder -> Advanced (Select link to alternate location) linked folder.

There you have your remote systems files synced up...

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this was to set up the connection to use the root user from the start. First, you need to enable it on your ssh client:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=86876

Then you may have to configure the authorized_keys file:
/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
to accept the key.

Hope that helps! It's not quite as secure, so be wary of this method.

Answer (score 0):

Other Workaround:
NOT ON LIVE SERVER!!!!

Assign the group of the files write rights during the period you are editing them and add your account to the group.

Comment: Is this a comment  or an answer to the question?